# Trying to use jQuery Mobile navbar as tabs to show/hide panes

Tags: events, jquery-mobile

Since there are no tabs in jQuery Mobile yet, I'm trying to use the navbar to get a similar effect. Here's my HTML code:

```
<div data-role="navbar">
    <ul>
        <li><a data-page="desc" href="#" class="ui-btn-active">Description</a></li>
        <li><a data-page="reviews" href="#">Reviews</a></li>
        <li><a data-page="qanda" href="#">Q&amp;A</a></li>
        <li><a data-page="parts" href="#">Parts&amp;Services</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div class="panes">
    <div data-page="desc">Howdy desc</div>
    <div data-page="reviews">Reviews</div>
    <div data-page="qanda">You gots questions?!</div>
    <div data-page="parts">Parts n stuff</div>
</div>
```

The problem is, for the life of me I cannot get any click handler to fire off on the iPad. I've tried attaching `$.click()` to the navbar li, the a tag.. NOTHING works. It works fine on the desktop and I can detect clicks in order to show/hide pages in the "panes" div. But on the iPad (our target), it does nothing. Totally stumped here. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using the `tap` event rather than click: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0b2/#/demos/1.0b2/docs/api/events.html

Comment: Note: You can also use the vclick event if you want to target both desktop and mobile

Comment: `vclick` can be tricky. On my main test device (Android 2.3.3 OS) `vclick` triggers multiple events (a simulated `vclick` and the real `click` about 300ms later) and can lead to multiple links being clicked by a single "tap". I like `vclick` because it is more responsive than the `click` event on mobile devices however that lag on the `click` event for mobile devices serves the purpose of deciding whether the user is clicking or scrolling.